# Uniform Convergence for $x^n(1-x)^n$ over [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am fairly new to the concept of supremum/infimum and slightly confused over idea of uniform convergence using these notations. According to the wiki for [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) we say that any $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $f(x)$ if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} sup|(f_n(x)-f(x))| = 0$.

Now my question is that for $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x)^n$ over [0,1] , If i take $f(x)$ = 1/4 how can I show that this equation holds. What I can see though that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} sup(|f_n(x)|) - f(x) = 0$ but won't value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} sup|(f_n(x)-f(x))|$ will be equal to 1/4?

Comment: Note that $f(x) = 1/4$ is not the limit function.  The sequence converges pointwise to $0$.  Since $x^n(1-x)^n$ has a maximum at $x = 1/2$ you have $\sup f_n(x) = 1/4^n \to 0$.

Comment: @RRL, Thanks for clarifying this. Now I know where I was wrong - I was taking $sup f_n(x) $ = 1/4 (Ignoring limit) and not $1/4^n$